# Como pegar o dyndns via php

Tags: php

Eu gostaria de pegar o `ip` que está no `dyndns` via *PHP*.

1. É possível fazer isso??
2. Se sim, por onde começo pesquisar?

Comment: Pegar da onde exatamente, o dyndns oferece vários serviço. Você quer converter o host como `seuhost.dyndns.com` para o numero do ip?

Comment: exatamente isso Guilherme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o [**`gethostbyname`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php), ele irá retornar o IP (IPv4) correspondente ao endereço, exemplo:

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('meu_host_foo_bar.dyndns.org');

echo $ip;
```

Um detalhe importante é que se o `gethostbyname` falhar em obter o endereço de ip ele irá retornar o próprio host o que pode confundir, então você pode checar assim:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'meu_host_foo_bar.dyndns.org';
$ip = gethostbyname($hostname);

if ($ip === $hostname) {
    echo 'Falha ao obter o IP de: ', $hostname;
} else {
    echo 'IP:', $ip;
}
```

Note que pode experimentar usar o [**`gethostbynamel`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php) que irá retornar uma lista em um array correspondente ao hostname passado:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'meu_host_foo_bar.dyndns.org';
$ips = gethostbynamel($hostname);

if (!$hosts) {
    echo 'Falha ao obter o IP de: ', $hostname;
} else {
    print_r($hosts);
}
```

Irá retornar algo como:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => 192.0.34.166
> )
> ```

Ou seja, dependendo do serviço poderá retornar mais de um, então poderá checar qual é o que você precisa. Acaso falhar irá retornar `false`.

Comment: Meu caro, acho que funcionou, só esperar a confirmação aqui